# Can my Hp Laptop be refreshed/reset

Tags: laptop

I have a HP Laptop. One day I was in the process of shutting it down. A message
stating that "Do not shut off computer finish updating". After it said 105 of
105 then the computer went off. Then following day when I tried to turn on the
laptop. A message said "Automatic fix repair", then updating..I saw a message
stated that windows did not load properly. I now have a blank screen...
I have programs that I loaded prior to this hiccup. My question is: Can my
laptop be refreshed/reset??? I was considering taking it to Best Buy Geek dept.
I have OS windows 8.1   I hope to hear from you very soon

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

This solution is to disable the automatic repair from starting if your computer fails to boot into windows.

**What you will need** - A Windows 8 or 8.1 CD

1. Place the CD in your drive and proceed to boot from it
2. When the install screen pops up, look to the bottom left and select "Repair Your Computer".
3. You will now see a screen that says "Choose an option". Select "Troubleshoot", then "Advanced Options", and finally "Command Prompt".
4. You should now see the command prompt. Type "bcdedit" (without quotes) and hit enter.
5. A list should have appeared. Towards the top, you should see "resumeobject" (It is under "default"). Highlight the long number, including the brackets, and copy.
6. Now type "bcdedit /set (the long number you copied) recoveryenabled No" (Without quotes). Hit enter.
7. You should now see the message "The operation completed successfully"
8. Type "Exit" (Without quotes)
9. Reboot

   ---

**Solution 2**

Booting into safe mode first, then rebooting the computer.

**What you will need** - nothing

So you are at the screen that says something on the lines of "Windows did not load properly".

1. Select "Advanced repair options"
2. Select "Troubleshoot"
3. Select "Advanced Options"
4. Select "Start up settings"
5. Select "Restart"
6. The computer should restart. Now you want to hit the 4 key, which is safe mode.
7. You should be able to log in now. Restart the computer and the computer should boot normally.

   ---

**Solution 3**

Running check disk to see if your hard drive is the problem

**What you will need** - A Windows 8 or 8.1 CD

1. Place the CD in your drive and proceed to boot from it
2. When the install screen pops up, look to the bottom left and select "Repair Your Computer".
3. You will now see a screen that says "Choose an option". Select "Troubleshoot", then "Advanced Options", and finally "Command Prompt".
4. Type "chkdsk /r C:" (Without quotes)
5. The scan should start. This could take several hours depending on the size of your hard drive.
6. Once the scan is done, type "exit" (without quotes).
7. Reboot

   ---

**Solution 4**

Making sure your hard drive is first in boot priority.

**What you will need** - nothing

1. Boot into BIOS on your computer
2. Go into your boot priority list
3. If you see "Windows Boot Manager" as number 1 in your priority, change it so that your hard drive is number 1.
4. Save and exit BIOS
5. Reboot

**If none of this works then re-install Windows.**